# Highchart configure appearance when x-axis has many categories

Tags: highcharts

I choose bar chart, because my graph has many categories, so I think it's a better aproach than a column chart.

I choose the following source code for making a start:

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/bar-stacked/

However, when I put many categories, the category labels get overlapped one each other. I firstly solved it making the container higher.
However the result is not as I expect, because I got a lot of "padding" between the beginning of the graph and the first category label, also between the last label and the end of the graph:

See fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Ra6Mc/20/

The code below:

```
 $(function () {
    var categories = ["ANALOGO","ANALOGO KLORNER","AÑADIR UNA PIEZA ","AÑADIR RESTO PIEZAS","ARANDELA DE ORO","ARANDELA ZOCALO","CAJITA","CALCINABLE","CALCINABLE DIAMETRO 4","CALCINABLE KLORNER","CARILLA EMPRES","COMPLETA DEFINITIVA","COMPLETA PROVISIONAL ","COMPOSTURA","COMPOSTURA PROTESIS","COMPOSTURA SIMPLE","CORONA CIRCONIO","CORONA CIRCONIO SOBRE IMPLANTE","CORONA EMPRESS SIN METAL","CORONA JACKET CERAMICA","CORONA METAL CERAMICA","CORONA PROVISIONAL CEMENTADA","CORONA SOBRE IMPLANTE","CUBETA DE RESINA","ESQUELETICO BILATERAL 1-3 PZAS","ESQUELETICO BILATERAL 3-5 PZAS","ESQUELETICO BILATERAL 5-8 PZAS","ESQUELETICO BILATERAL 8-14 PZAS","ESQUELETICO UNILATERAL 1-3 PZAS","FERULA DE BLANQUEAMIENTO","FERULA DESCARGA","GANCHO UNIDAD","IMPLANTE PROVISIONAL ATORNILLADO","MERYLAND PIEZA","PARCIAL ACRILICO 10 PZAS O MUÑON","PARCIAL ACRILICO DE 1-3 PZAS","PARCIAL ACRILICO DE 4 PZAS","PARCIAL ACRILICO DE 5 PZAS","PARCIAL ACRILICO DE 6 PZAS","PARCIAL ACRILICO DE 7 PZAS","PARCIAL ACRILICO DE 8 PZAS","PARCIAL ACRILICO DE 9 PZAS","PARCIAL ACRILICO PROV. 10 PZAS O MUÑÓN","PARCIAL ACRILICO PROV. DE 1-3 PZAS","PARCIAL ACRILICO PROV. DE 4 PZAS","PARCIAL ACRILICO PROV. DE 5 PZAS","PARCIAL ACRILICO PROV. DE 6 PZAS","PARCIAL ACRILICO PROV. DE 7 PZAS","PERNO MUÑON COLADO","PERNO MUÑON DOBLE COLADO","PILAR ANGULADO","PROTESIS HIBRIDA","REBASE PROTESIS","REPARACION ARCADA CERAMICA","REPARACION CERAMICA","REPLICA DIAMETRO 5 MM","SOBREDENTADURA CON LOCATOR","SOLDADURA","TORNILLO AVINENT","TORNILLO KLORNER","TORNILLO TITANIO","VARIOS"];
        $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'bar'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Stacked bar chart'
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: categories
            },
            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                title: {
                    text: 'Total fruit consumption'
                }
            },
            legend: {
                backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
                reversed: true
            },
            plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    stacking: 'normal'
                }
            },
                series: [

              {   
                  name:'COMPANY-3',
                  data: [
                  [categories.indexOf("FERULA DESCARGA"),13],[categories.indexOf("ESQUELETICO BILATERAL 8-14 PZAS"),1],[categories.indexOf("ESQUELETICO BILATERAL 5-8 PZAS"),3],[categories.indexOf("PARCIAL ACRILICO PROV. DE 7 PZAS"),1],[categories.indexOf("CORONA CIRCONIO SOBRE IMPLANTE"),14],[categories.indexOf("GANCHO UNIDAD"),76],[categories.indexOf("ESQUELETICO BILATERAL 3-5 PZAS"),1],[categories.indexOf("COMPLETA PROVISIONAL "),36],[categories.indexOf("PARCIAL ACRILICO DE 4 PZAS"),15],[categories.indexOf("ANALOGO"),1],[categories.indexOf("PARCIAL ACRILICO PROV. DE 1-3 PZAS"),3],[categories.indexOf("CORONA CIRCONIO"),27],[categories.indexOf("AÑADIR 1ª PIEZA "),1],[categories.indexOf("MERYLAND PIEZA"),5],[categories.indexOf("TORNILLO TITANIO"),37],[categories.indexOf("COMPLETA DEFINITIVA"),1],[categories.indexOf("CORONA PROVISIONAL CEMENTADA"),16],[categories.indexOf("SOBREDENTADURA CON LOCATOR"),3],[categories.indexOf("TORNILLO AVINENT"),44],[categories.indexOf("REPARACION CERAMICA"),2],[categories.indexOf("ARANDELA DE ORO"),8],[categories.indexOf("CORONA SOBRE IMPLANTE"),651],[categories.indexOf("VARIOS"),30],[categories.indexOf("CORONA METAL CERAMICA"),67],[categories.indexOf("ARANDELA ZOCALO"),30],[categories.indexOf("PARCIAL ACRILICO DE 6 PZAS"),1],[categories.indexOf("REPLICA DIAMETRO 5 MM"),1],[categories.indexOf("PARCIAL ACRILICO 10 PZAS O MÁS"),1],[categories.indexOf("PARCIAL ACRILICO DE 1-3 PZAS"),19],[categories.indexOf("ESQUELETICO BILATERAL 1-3 PZAS"),2],[categories.indexOf("PARCIAL ACRILICO PROV. 10 PZAS O MÁS"),1],[categories.indexOf("AÑADIR RESTO PIEZAS"),1],[categories.indexOf("CORONA JACKET CERAMICA"),6],[categories.indexOf("PROTESIS HIBRIDA"),44]
                  ]},

                    {   
                        name:'COMPANY-5',
                        data: [
                            [categories.indexOf("CALCINABLE"),2],[categories.indexOf("CORONA METAL CERAMICA"),4],[categories.indexOf("GANCHO UNIDAD"),11],[categories.indexOf("VARIOS"),2],[categories.indexOf("CORONA SOBRE IMPLANTE"),26],[categories.indexOf("COMPLETA DEFINITIVA"),1],[categories.indexOf("ANALOGO"),3],[categories.indexOf("PARCIAL ACRILICO PROV. 10 PZAS O MÁS"),1],[categories.indexOf("TORNILLO TITANIO"),20],[categories.indexOf("PILAR ANGULADO"),2],[categories.indexOf("PARCIAL ACRILICO DE 1-3 PZAS"),3],[categories.indexOf("CALCINABLE DIAMETRO 4"),18],[categories.indexOf("TORNILLO AVINENT"),1],[categories.indexOf("PARCIAL ACRILICO DE 5 PZAS"),1]
                        ]},
                    {
                        name:'COMPANY-6.',
                        data: [
                            [categories.indexOf("PROTESIS HIBRIDA"),28],[categories.indexOf("COMPLETA PROVISIONAL "),1],[categories.indexOf("IMPLANTE PROVISIONAL ATORNILLADO"),1],[categories.indexOf("REPARACION CERAMICA"),5],[categories.indexOf("CORONA JACKET CERAMICA"),3],[categories.indexOf("TORNILLO KLORNER"),1],[categories.indexOf("PERNO MUÑON COLADO"),2],[categories.indexOf("FERULA DESCARGA"),14],[categories.indexOf("CORONA EMPRESS SIN METAL"),4],[categories.indexOf("CORONA PROVISIONAL CEMENTADA"),16],[categories.indexOf("CORONA CIRCONIO SOBRE IMPLANTE"),1],[categories.indexOf("PARCIAL ACRILICO DE 4 PZAS"),1],[categories.indexOf("COMPLETA DEFINITIVA"),1],[categories.indexOf("CORONA CIRCONIO"),4],[categories.indexOf("VARIOS"),2],[categories.indexOf("CALCINABLE KLORNER"),1],[categories.indexOf("CORONA METAL CERAMICA"),25],[categories.indexOf("ANALOGO KLORNER"),1],[categories.indexOf("CORONA SOBRE IMPLANTE"),322],[categories.indexOf("SOBREDENTADURA CON LOCATOR"),9],[categories.indexOf("CARILLA EMPRES"),2],[categories.indexOf("GANCHO UNIDAD"),2]
                        ]},
                    {   
                        name:'COMPANY-7',
                        data: [
                            [categories.indexOf("CALCINABLE"),1],[categories.indexOf("CORONA SOBRE IMPLANTE"),2],[categories.indexOf("CORONA METAL CERAMICA"),6],[categories.indexOf("REPARACION CERAMICA"),3],[categories.indexOf("PROTESIS HIBRIDA"),1]
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          ]}                ]
        });
    });
```

Just to know:
- On my navigator I can see all the category labels, however with jsfiddle I only get some of them.
- Not all my series have all the data, thats why I put the data in the series with the expression categories.indexOf().

Comment: Couple problems right off the top: 1.) data is not sorted properly.  Series data has to be sorted by the implementer, that's why your fiddle throws this error: http://www.highcharts.com/errors/15 over and over 2.) You are asking for the `.indexOf` things that don't exist in your categories array.

Comment: Simple sorter: http://jsfiddle.net/Fusher/Ra6Mc/42/